# What is the best way to use a MapFragment in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I have a ViewPager with two tabs in the first one is a list of places and the second I want to be a map of the places. Now I can populate the list from the database and I have the map working in another place in the app but I'm having trouble making it work with the tab layout as a fragment.

Here's the code for my map fragment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnInfoWindowClickListener,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    LatLngBounds.Builder build = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    GoogleMap map;

    double[] lats;
    double[] lngs;
    String[] names;
    String[] types;
    int count;
    int[] ids;

    // @Override
    // public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    // Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // View v = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_map,
    // container, false);
    // setUpMapIfNeeded(null, null);
    // setupMarkers();
    // LatLngBounds bounds = build.build();
    // setUpMapIfNeeded(null, bounds);
    // return v;
    // }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map);

        // setUpMapIfNeeded(null, null);

        // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private void setupMarkers() {
        // get the passed crags names and locations
        // double[] lats = getArguments().getDoubleArray(ClimbProvider.LAT);
        // double[] lngs = getArguments().getDoubleArray(ClimbProvider.LONG);
        // ArrayList<String> names = getArguments().getStringArrayList(
        // ClimbProvider.NAME);
        // interate and add every passed crag to the map as a marker
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // add the crags name and location to the marker
            LatLng pos = new LatLng(lats[i], lngs[i]);
            options.position(pos);
            options.title((String) names[i]);
            // add the marker to the map
            map.addMarker(options);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            build.include(pos);
        }
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(MarkerOptions options,
            final LatLngBounds bounds) {
        if (options == null && bounds == null) {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
        } else if (bounds != null) {
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            try {
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 70));
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // layout not yet initialised
                final View mapView = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map).getView();
                if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
                    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                                // We check which build version we are using.
                                @Override
                                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                        mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                                .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                                                        this);
                                    } else {
                                        mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                                .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                                                        this);
                                    }
                                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                            .newLatLngBounds(bounds, 70));
                                }
                            });
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // when an info bubble is clicked get its title and search for it in the
    // list of crag names the cross reference this with the list of crag ids and
    // pass that to the view crag activity
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        int id = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (names[i].contentEquals(marker.getTitle())) {
                id = ids[i];
            }
        }
        Intent viewCrag = new Intent(getActivity(), CragViewActivity.class);
        viewCrag.putExtra("id", id);
        Log.d("ClimbTrack", "row id = " + id);
        startActivity(viewCrag);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created. This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri allcrags = Uri
                .parse("content://com.fooforever.climbtrack.provider/crags");
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), allcrags, null, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        ArrayList<Double> latsArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> lngsArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Integer> idsArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> typesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Swap the new cursor in. (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        // mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        // move to the top of the query results
        data.moveToFirst();
        // put all the ids from the result into a list so they can be
        // referenced against the listview item id
        while (data.isAfterLast() == false) {
            idsArray.add(data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(ClimbProvider._ID)));
            latsArray
                    .add(data.getDouble(data.getColumnIndex(ClimbProvider.LAT)));
            lngsArray.add(data.getDouble(data
                    .getColumnIndex(ClimbProvider.LONG)));
            namesArray.add(data.getString(data
                    .getColumnIndex(ClimbProvider.NAME)));
            typesArray.add(data.getString(data
                    .getColumnIndex(ClimbProvider.TYPE)));
            data.moveToNext();
        }

        count = data.getCount();
        lats = new double[count];
        lngs = new double[count];
        names = new String[count];
        types = new String[count];
        ids = new int[count];
        convert_arr_double(latsArray, lats);
        convert_arr_double(lngsArray, lngs);
        convert_arr_string(namesArray, names);
        convert_arr_string(typesArray, types);
        convert_arr_int(idsArray, ids);

        // The list should now be shown.
        // if (isResumed()) {
        // setListShown(true);
        // } else {
        // setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        // }
        setupMarkers();
        LatLngBounds bounds = build.build();
        setUpMapIfNeeded(null, bounds);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO
    }

    // convert the passed arraylist to a double array
    private void convert_arr_double(ArrayList<Double> array, double[] out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            out[i] = array.get(i);
        }
    }

    private void convert_arr_string(ArrayList<String> array, String[] out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            out[i] = array.get(i);
        }
    }

    private void convert_arr_int(ArrayList<Integer> array, int[] out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            out[i] = array.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compile error on the initialisation of the map in the setupmapifneeded() function.

```
The method getMap() is undefined for the type MapFragment
```

on line 88 4/5th line of the setupmap ifneeded() function.

I cannot figure out why I'm getting the compile error here and is this the best way to implement this sort of feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `ViewPager` to navigate between a list and a map may produce some frustrating behaviour - attempting to pan the map may result in switching views, or vice versa.

You could either use plain tab navigation (which removes any of the panning/view switching frustrations) or you could implement a 'lock' button for your map view to lock the panning.

As to why you're getting a compilation error:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnInfoWindowClickListener,
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    ...
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

<del>You're casting to the wrong type of `MapFragment`. Either rename *your* `MapFragment` (say, `AppNameMapFragment`) or fully qualify the cast:</del>

You were previously attempting to cast from a `Fragment` to *your* `MapFragment`. In my previous answer I missed that you're also using the support library. So, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager`, and you need to cast to `SupportMapFragment`:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: "attempting to pan the map may result in switching views, or vice versa" -- subclass `ViewPager`, override `canScroll()`, and indicate there that touch events on the map should go to the map. Here is a sample application demonstrating this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager

Comment: That's effective for pages where you can touch somewhere outside of the map to initiate a change to another page; with pages where the whole view is a Map, this produces inconsistent behaviour, doesn't it? Swipe to change page when on the List, but tap the page indicator at the top to change page when on the Map?

Comment: "with pages where the whole view is a Map, this produces inconsistent behaviour, doesn't it?" -- correct, and my sample somewhat demonstrates this, as the only way you can change pages is via the tabs. However, `ViewPager` is still a more flexible way than many alternatives (e.g., `FragmentTabHost`) of implementing tabs. Without tabs or the equivalent, a map taking up the full page makes the `ViewPager` pointless, so that's a UI design bug. I am not a fan of the OP's UI design (list in one page, map in another), as IMHO that is a misuse of `ViewPager` and horizontal swiping.

Comment: +1 about the misuse of `ViewPager` for this scenario. Thanks for the clarification; was concerned I was somehow misunderstanding how a `ViewPager` works.

Comment: Thanks guys, I hear you about the probable UI weirdness using a `ViewPager` (hadn't thought of that) but I'm going to try it and see what happens anyway.  Although changing the name of the class doesn't help the compile error, I still get the same thing... any ideas?

Comment: If you mouse-over `MapFragment` (at declaration of your `map` variable, or when you're casting it), what package does it say it belongs to?

Comment: @AdamS sorry the name changed hadn't applied, I now get `Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment` I have used this exact statement before I cant work out why its not working.

Comment: @fooforever Did you try fully qualifying it?

Comment: Ugh, I wasn't reading your code right. I hope you haven't declared your `map` variable as a `MapFragment`. Oops. Will update my answer, but I'm not sure that that's your error.

Comment: Aha, I see from your imports you're using the support library for fragments; you need to be using `getSupportFragmentManager()`, and casting to `SupportMapFragment`.